# How to debug a C# .NET application in Visual Studio 2010 that is started from another process

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a .NET GUI application written in C# and a PDF printer. The PDF printer has a field where you can set a command to start an external application.

In this case, I can print a document with this printer and the printer starts my EXE file with the filepath to the generated PDF file as argument. How can I debug my application when it is started from the printer?

In Visual Studio 2010, I can set debug information for command line arguments, and this works fine. But if the application is started from the printer the application doesn't work fine. Therefore I want to debug my application when it is started from printer. How can I do this? Is there a parameter to start an EXE file in debug mode or something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can attach to a process when it starts using a small registry tweak.

Go to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
```

Create a new key with the name of the executable as it will appear in [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager), for example, `myapp.exe`. Under this, create a new string value called `debugger` and set it to `vsjitdebugger.exe`.

Now, when the EXE file is triggered, a window will appear asking which debugger to attach to.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this is what i was searching for.

Comment: I have a problem! When i remove the created registry entry it has no effect. A window is still appearing and asking which debugger to attach!

Answer (score 9):

Try to attach to the process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx

> To attach to a running process
>   1.On the Debug menu, select Attach to Process. If no project is open, select
>   Attach to Process on the Tools menu.
>
> 2.In the Attach to Process dialog box, find the program that you want to
>   attach to from the Available Processes
>   list.
>
> a.If the program that you want to
>   debug is running on another computer,
>   you must first select the remote
>   computer. For more information, see
>   How to: Select a Remote Machine.
>
> b.If the process is running under a
>   different user account, select the
>   Show processes from all users check
>   box.
>
> c.If you are connected through Remote
>   Desktop Connection, select the Show
>   processes in all sessions check box.
>
> 3.In the Attach to box, make sure that the type of code you will debug is
>   listed. The default Automatic setting
>   tries to determine what type of code
>   you want to debug. If the automatic
>   setting is not appropriate:
>
> a.Click Select.
>
> b.In the Select Code Type dialog box,
>   click Debug these code types and
>   select the types to debug.
>
> c.Click OK.
>
> 4.Click Attach.
>
> The Available Processes list is
>   displayed automatically when you open
>   the Processes dialog box. Processes
>   can start and stop in the background
>   while the dialog box is open. However,
>   the contents are not always current.
>   You can refresh the list at any time
>   to see the current list of processes
>   by clicking Refresh.
>
> You can be attached to multiple
>   programs when you are debugging, but
>   only one program is active in the
>   debugger at any time. You can set the
>   active program in the Debug Location
>   toolbar or the Processes window. For
>   more information, see How to: Set the
>   Current Program.
>
> All Debug menu execution commands
>   affect the active program. You can
>   break any debugged program from the
>   Processes dialog box or break all
>   attached programs from the Debug menu.
>   For more information, see How to:
>   Break Execution.

Comment: The problem is that the process is not running. When i print a document from e.g. Word, the printer only makes a pdf file and opens my exe. So there is no process running to attach.

Comment: what is the host process for your application?

Comment: you can attach to the host process. i.e when debugging sharepoint in the past / present we attached to the IIS process.

Comment: I think the printer who starts my app, isn't it?

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a call into your code that explicitly requests that the debugger be attached at the current location. This has been around since Win32 days, and surfaces in .NET as [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) (and [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx)).

You can also add logic to decide when to trigger this if you don't want to do it the first time through:

```
   #if DEBUG
      if (++staticCounter > 3) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
   #endif
```

And, of course, you'll want to disable it for production.