# Remove registry entry to attach a process when it starts

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, process, registry

I have entered a Registry Key to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options

I used this to debug my application when it starts. But now i want remove the entry, but nothing changed. I restarted my pc but still the same. Why does the window that asks me to debug still appears though i rmoved the entry?

This question depends on [How to debug a C# .NET application in Visual Studio 2010 that is started from another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074121/how-to-debug-a-c-net-application-in-vs2010-that-is-started-from-another-process)

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the related registry settings?

Comment: I included a screenshot. Do u have any idea?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking; is the registry entry _not_ deleting (or returning after you've deleted it).  Or is the debugger prompt still appearing despite having deleted the registry setting?

Comment: The debugger prompt is still appearing despite having deleted the registry key.

Comment: In that picture the key still exists - which is why the debugger is launching. Notice that the key is in the system wide HKLM - you'll need to have elevated administrator access to delete it.

Comment: After several restarts the debugger does not start anymore. I am wondering why windows needs more than 3 restarts to take effect...

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that your application still has a bug that triggers the debugger ?

For example, forget a DebugBreak() somewhere or write any code that throws an unhandled exception and Windows will lauch the debugger to it.

I usually prompts you before, though. Check the value of this key and make sure `Auto` is set to `0`

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

If that trigger is soon in your application startup code, it will look like it's Windows who's starting the debugger.

ps: It [happened to me](http://www.paralint.com/blog/2009/11/25/aucun-reboots-computer-unless-a-debugger-is-present/) as I was trying to find a way around [a remote debugging problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310453/show-source-code-in-windbg-when-running-a-process-through-ntsd-d).