# Make externally-run debug build executable exception open in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have one developing computer and one beta-test-computer. On the beta I run Debug-build executables copied from the VS project Debug folder of developing computer.  Is there any way to make the exceptions occurring on these executables to open in VS (on the beta-pc where it runs) as if it was a normal debug run?

I recall earlier I got a popup question if I want to debug an exception in VS, though always declined, but currently I only get a standard exception-popup.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer; see if it works.

Be sure to also copy all .PDB files related to the binaries.

Open Visual Studio first. Then, run your executable and attach Visual Studio's debugger to the executable. When your process raises an unhandled exception, Visual Studio should be able to debug it as if it was a normal application you were developing, complete with tracing and local watches.

I'm not sure if this is necessary if you only want a full stack trace. Calling `Exception.ToString()` returns the full stack trace.

Comment: Yes I was not accurate, I'm looking for more than the full stack trace. If there's no easier way I'll do this attach-to-process.

Comment: I'm not sure, but according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4145883/555547) post and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6074238/555547) post, any shortcuts haven't been mentioned (it seems a debugger must first be attached).